# Resource-related error condition in Windows Forms C++ application

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, embedded-resource

I am working on a legacy Windows Forms application using VS 2008 under C++ and face a weird problem. The form uses an ImageList object, to which two bitmap images have been added. At run-time, I get the following error in Debug mode (in the Release mode, the application just doens't launch):

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.
Make sure "MyApp.Form1.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MyApp" at compile time, 
or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

The crash occurs at the first line of this block:

```
this->imageList1->ImageStream = (__try_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ImageListStreamer*  >(resources->GetObject(S"imageList1.ImageStream")));
this->imageList1->TransparentColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
this->imageList1->Images->SetKeyName(0, S"Nok32.png");
this->imageList1->Images->SetKeyName(1, S"Ok32.png");
```

This is pretty puzzling, because I copied the application from an existing one which works fine. I just changed the namespaces. And if I remove the two images from the list, the application works.

I found several posts on forums about this or similar problems, but none could really help me. I don't think that Visual Studio can be blamed. I tried with frameworks 2.0 and 3.0, to no avail. Fully comparing the sources of both applications, I can't see a significant difference.

Any hint ?

Comment: The ResourceManager object is not initialized correctly.  The namespace for the resource is normally the hangup.  Diagnose with ildasm.exe, look at the .resource names in the manifest.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans. Though I have solved the problem, you can enter your comment as an answer, which I will accept. I wasted about a day on this issue, mostly by lack of troubleshooting means.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: there was an old namespace left in the project file (.vcproj) !